# Help converting an exponential in cosine form

Tags: trigonometry, exponential-function

I have:

$$ \text{P}(x) = \frac{1}{25}|1+ 4e^{-ix}|^2 $$

I want to write this using cosine functions. According to the answer sheet, it can be rewritten in the form:

$$ \text{P}(x) = \frac{1}{25}(17 + 8\cos{x}) $$

I just can not seem to reach this result. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{1}{25} |1 + 4 e^{-ix}|^2$?

Comment: Yes, I've changed it now!

Comment: Could you show us your process for starting with the givens and (not quite) arriving at the desired form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Expand it out using the definition of the magnitude of the complex number, and you will get
$$\frac{1}{25} (1 + 4e^{-ix})(1 + 4e^{-ix})^*$$
where the asterisk denotes the complex conjugate. Since the complex conjugate of $e^{i\alpha}$ is just $e^{-i \alpha}$, the expression becomes
$$\frac{1}{25} (1 + 4e^{-ix})(1 + 4e^{ix}) = \frac{1}{25}\left(1 + 16 + 4 [e^{ix} + e^{-ix}]\right)$$
From here, use the identity
$$\cos x = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-i x}}{2}$$
(This identity is not too difficult to prove, just use the fact that $e^{ix} = \cos x + i \sin x$. Note that $\sin$ and $\cos$ are odd and even, respectively.)

Comment: Thank you, I forgot that you had to multiply out by the complex conjugate!